# Solving $x$ in the equation $2\sin(x)−\sqrt{3}=0$.

Tags: trigonometry

So I already tried answering the question and as far as I know my method is correct. 
Its just that this is one question in a multiple choice question and my solutions don't match up with any of the solutions provided.

$2\sin(x)−\sqrt3=0$

$\Rightarrow 2\sin(x) = \sqrt 3$

$\Rightarrow \sin(x) = \sqrt3/2$

$\Rightarrow x = \arcsin(\sqrt3/2)$

$\Rightarrow x = \pi/3$ or $x = 2\pi/3$

so thats as far as I got. However when comparing to the answers provided it was incorrect.

An example of one of the answers provided is: $x=\pi/3+2n\pi$, $x=2\pi/3+2n\pi\
 (n\in\Bbb{Z})$

And im not sure what steps to take get to this point/how to get the $2n\pi$ part.

Comment: The sine is a periodic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the $2\pi n$ part is that the sine function is periodic. No matter what you input into it, if you input that same thing plus $2\pi n$ for some integer $n$, then you get the same thing. Thus if $x_0$ is such that $\sin(x_0)$ has some specific value (in this case $\frac{\sqrt3}2$), then $\sin(x_0+2\pi)$ will also have that value, as will $\sin(x_0 + 4\pi), \sin(x_0 + 6\pi), \sin(x_0-2\pi)$, and so on. This is something you need to keep in mind always when you solve equations with trigonometric functions.

Comment: Oh right. I think i get it. So basically the 2πn part is syntax to show that the solution is the same for n number of periods. So the way I solved it is correct but you add the 2πn part to show that the solutions are the same for any n number of periods?

Comment: @John That's exactly it. What you found are all solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$. In order to find all solutions on the entire number line, you have to add all possible integer multiples of $2\pi$ to the two solutions you have found.

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*

The function $\cos x$ is a periodic function, one for which $f(x+T)=f(x)$. In practical terms it means that a periodic function "revisits" all of its values, in this case the value $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

The solution given is representative of this fact, since for different values of $n$ you "revisit" the value of the equation.

And a little graph to demonstrate things better-
[image]